# Why RadioGroup Selecting multiple RadioButtons

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have added 2 RadioButtons under RadioGroup and enabled first one, when i selecting second one its not deselecting first one. can you suggest me what was the wrong in this

Here is my xml:

```
<RadioGroup 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="NO"/>
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="YES"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Your `RadioButton`s need IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This:

```
<RadioGroup 
        android:id="@+id/radioGrp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="NO"/>
        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="YES"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give IDs to all radio buttons. It'll work.

```
android:id="@+id/radioButton1/2/3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `android:checked="true"` makes it selected infinitely.

Try defaulting first button in your code.

```
radiogroup.check(idOfYourFirstRadio)
```

You need to set IDs to your Views.

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:checked="true" and should be good